# How to make a child span the grid from the first to the last gap?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a parent grid of 12 columns and a gap of 24px between each column. I want to render a child grid that will start from end of column 1 or start from first gap and end to the last gap, How can I achieve this?

Here's an example of what I want:

[image: Check this image for better understanding]

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  column-gap: 24px;
}

.grid div {
  grid-column: ???;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid"> 
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make the element to span from the second column to before the last column then use negative margin:

```css
.grid {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 24px;
}

.grid div {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  grid-column: 2 / -2;
  margin: 0 -24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

[image]

You can also do it like below:

```css
.grid {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 24px;
}

.grid div {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  grid-column: 2 / -2;
  width: calc(100% + 48px);
  justify-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @temani is there way to to it without adding negative margin

Comment: @AvinashAnshu what the issue with negative margin?

Comment: there is no issue it is working perfectly fine with negative margin, I was just thinking is there any other way or not but thank you it's working perfectly

Comment: @AvinashAnshu we can for sure find more tricks but all of them around the same idea; making your element overflow into the gap (another example: https://jsfiddle.net/d61nrmw2/)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Just saved my own code with that `width: calc(100% + 48px);`. Can't think of a better way to have done it!